# How to Organize Functions (That Use Multiple Packages) Into a Single File

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have about 5 python functions that I have written that I wanted to organize into a single file (functions.py.)  I then import that file into my main python script as such:

```
import functions
```

The issue that I am having is these functions rely on multiple python packages. Even when I import them into my main python script, the functions are unable to recognize them.

Could anybody please explain the proper way of organizing functions into separate files, when these functions rely on multiple packages?

Comment: You need to import the packages in the file where you need to use them. If the functions are in functions.py, then you need to import the dependencies there, not in the main Python script. You will have to provide a [mcve] if you need more details.

Comment: I appreciate the response!  This is actually what I've been doing, so it looks like downstream errors are due to something with the python code, rather than not being able to utilize dependencies.  Cheers!